# iOS app compatibility issue with iphone and ipad in Publishing

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, compatibility

I developed an app that only runs on iPhone (iPad compatibility not required yet by me). After I publish it to the app store, the apple rejects the app as they test it on iPad and as I mention that it is only iPhone app, therefore, it looks ugly on iPad.
How could I submit it to app store by force apply the setting that it is an iPhone app only, not iPad? 
This creates really much issue as I worked a lot and seeing this rejection made my heartbreak.

Answer (score 0):

Apple have stated in their app-store guide lines that iPhone apps should run on  iPad. Unless there is some really special need otherwise, which you must be able reason with them.

Check here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

[image]

In addition to that it is really easy to make iPhone application compatible in most of the cases, just try and run it once on iPad device( or simulator), and you might find the crash and be able to fix that easy.